# Why can't i change the shape or dimensions of my list?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, image-classification, supervised-learning

```
target = []
images = []

flattened_data =[]
```

these are 3 lists I made to append my dataset after the preprocessing, but haven't been able to do so until now because of the difference in the dimensions of these lists and the lists which I want to append into these lists.

```
flattened_data = np.array(flattened_data)
flattened_data = flattened_data.reshape(flat.shape)
```

When I try to append using this method this error below is what I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-f79792c8d9c0> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 flattened_data = np.array(flattened_data)
----> 2 flattened_data = flattened_data.reshape(flat.shape)
      3 for category in class_names:  # Iterate over the list of category names
      4     for img in os.listdir(path):
      5 

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (67500,)
```

Here, `flat` is the list I get after running the code below.

```
for category in class_names:  # Iterate over the list of category names
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = imread(os.path.join(path, img))
        img_resized = resize(img_array,(150,150,3))
        flat =  img_resized.flatten()
```

Just like this case, I have two more lists which I want to append in target and images respectively but haven't been able to so due to same error, i.e. difference in shape or dimension.

Comment: @9769953 yes i checked the datatype all the lists I defined myself are lists.  I had to to use vstack  call because `.append()` was showing some other errors .that's why I decided to change it to numpy array then use vstack

Comment: @9769953 Oh sorry, i read it again. are you trying to say that I have to ensure that flattened_data contains the data I  want,  should make sure that the code responsible for appending data to it is executed as expected ??

Comment: i also want to mention that `for category in class_names:  # Iterate over the list of category names
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = imread(os.path.join(path, img))
        img_resized = resize(img_array,(150,150,3))
        flat =  img_resized.flatten()` this code comes before the code below `flattened_data = np.array(flattened_data)
flattened_data = flattened_data.reshape(flat.shape)
for category in class_names:  # Iterate over the list of category names
    for img in os.listdir(path):

      np.vstack((flattened_data,flat))`

Comment: well, that is the main problem i haven't been able to add the data I want to add the data I want to add

Comment: then what do you suggest other than flattening the image?? (the code you gave is running perfectly, don't know why I was having an error when I was using .append() before)

Answer (score -1):

```
flattened_data = []

for category in class_names:  # Iterate over the list of category names
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = imread(os.path.join(path, img))
        img_resized = resize(img_array,(150,150,3))
        flattened_data.append(img_resized.flatten())

flattened_data = np.hstack(flattened_data)
# or
# flattened_data = np.vstack(flattened_data)
# if you want to add it as an extra dimension
```